# ¿Cómo hacer una actualización con una suma de columna mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Antes de nada, muchas gracias a cualquiera que ayude.

Necesito hacer el siguiente ejercicio en mysql workbench:

Ejercicio 3: (UPDATE)

Abre la BD Ventasy realiza las siguientes 
operaciones:

a) Añadir  una  nueva  tabla,  llamada ejercicio31,  a  la  BD Ventas.  Esta  nueva  tabla contendrá  los  códigos  de  todos  los  productos  existentes,  sus  precios  y  sus existencias, así como el número total de unidades vendidas. A este último campo se  llamará cantidadvendida con  valor  0  por  defecto si  el  producto  no  se  ha vendido nunca.

Primero he creado la tabla así:

```
CREATE TABLE `ventas2`.`ejercicio31` (
  `CodProducto` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `PRECIO` INT NULL,
  `Existencias` INT NULL,
  `CantidadVendido` INT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodProducto`));
```

Luego he insertado todos los productos con el id, el precio y las existencias, de esta manera:

```
insert into ejercicio31 (CodProducto, PRECIO, Existencias) 
    select IDPRODUCTO, PRECIO, EXISTENCIAS from producto;
```

Me queda insertar el número de artículos vendido, que supongo, por el enunciado, debo hacerlo con un update, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo T-T.

```
update ejercicio31 set CantidadVendido = sum(cant);
```

Obviamente, esa burrada no ha funcionado. Y no sé cómo se podría hacer.

En la BBDD ventas, tengo muchas tablas, creo que aquí tendría que usar la tabla de productos y la tabla líneas de pedido, en donde tengo la cantidad de productos que se han vendido por líneas de pedido; os pongo, por si hiciera falta los campos de ambas tablas.

Tabla ejercicio31:

```
CodProducto, PRECIO, Existencias, CantidadVendido
```

Tabla Producto:

```
IDPRODUCTO, DESCRIPCION, PRECIO, EXISTENCIAS
```

Tabla líneaspedido:

```
NUMPEDIDO, NUMLINEA, IDPRODUCTO, CANT, IMPORTE
```

Comment: Dado que se trata de un ejercicio, dinos si te es permitido usar `JOIN` para resolver esto. Si unes `EJERCICIO31` con `LINEASPEDIDO` en el `UPDATE` lo podrás resolver con suma facilidad.

Comment: Pues no domino el uso del join todavía, ¡Por cierto!, gracias por editar el post y perdón por colocarlo mal. ¿Cómo hago para poner correctamente las sentencias sql?

Aunque no lo domino, puedo usarlo y me vendría bien ver un ejemplo de cómo usarlo.

Gracias!

Comment: Para poner bien el código, solamente copias/pegas el bloque completo, luego lo seleccionas y pulsas en la imagen `{ }` que es para identar todo el bloque (darle espacios a la izquierda) y así quedará perfecto. En cuanto a la pregunta, ahora te pongo un ejemplo. También se puede hacer con sub-consultas, como indicas más abajo, pero con `JOIN` se entiende mejor (según mi criterio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo mediante `JOIN`. Aquí en la parte del `INNER JOIN` recuperarás los datos de la tabla de la cual se tomarán los valores que serán usados para actualizar la columna `CantidadVendido`.

Esta consulta actualizará todos los registros sin distinción.

```
UPDATE ejercicio31 ej 
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT idproducto, SUM(cant) mysum
   FROM lineaspedido 
   GROUP BY idproducto
) lp ON ej.CodProducto = lp.idproducto
SET ej.CantidadVendido = lp.mysum;
```

Y, si quieres aplicar algún filtro, sólo agregas un `WHERE` al final. Por ejemplo aquí, sólo se actualizará el producto con código `1`:

```
UPDATE ejercicio31 ej 
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT idproducto, SUM(cant) mysum
   FROM lineaspedido 
   GROUP BY idproducto
) lp ON ej.CodProducto = lp.idproducto
SET ej.CantidadVendido = lp.mysum
WHERE ej.CodProducto=1;
```

También lo puedes hacer con una sub-consulta usando `WHERE`. En SQL esta práctica se conoce como *join implícito*. O sea, lo que ocurre es un `JOIN`, aunque no aparece reflejado en la consulta, dado que en vez de `JOIN` usas `WHERE` para unir las tablas por `CodProducto` y `idproducto`.

Answer (score 0):

Publico la respuesta, que al final, he conseguido dar con ella. No era difícil, pero me estaba liando mucho y todavía no entiendo muy bien el uso de las subselect.

(Lo siento si la posteo mal, pero no sé cómo ponerlo para que aparezca con el cuadrado al rededor)

```
/* Insertar datos productos.*/

insert into ejercicio31 (CodProducto, PRECIO, Existencias) select IDPRODUCTO, PRECIO, EXISTENCIAS from producto;


/* Insertar Unidades vendidas */
update ejercicio31, (select idproducto, sum(cant) mysum from lineaspedido group by idproducto) t set CantidadVendido = mysum where codproducto = idproducto
```

;